# Memory-constrained external sorting of strings, with duplicates combined&counted, on a critical server (billions of filenames)

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, dictionary, large-data

Our server produces files like `{c521c143-2a23-42ef-89d1-557915e2323a}-sign.xml` in its log folder. The first part is GUID; the second part is name template.

I want to count the number of files with same name template. For instance, we have

```
{c521c143-2a23-42ef-89d1-557915e2323a}-sign.xml
{aa3718d1-98e2-4559-bab0-1c69f04eb7ec}-hero.xml
{0c7a50dc-972e-4062-a60c-062a51c7b32c}-sign.xml
```

The result should be

```
sign.xml,2
hero.xml,1
```

The total kinds of possible name templates is unknown, possibly exceeds `int.MaxValue`.

The total number of files on the server is unknown, possibly exceeds `int.MaxValue`.

**Requirements**:

The final result should be sorted by name template.

The server on which the tool is going to run is super critical. We should be able to tell memory usage (MB) and the number of temporary files generated, if any, before running the tool and without knowing any characteristic of the log folder.

We use C# language.

**My idea**:

- For the first 5000 files, count the occurrences, write result to `Group1.txt`.
- For the second 5000 files, count the occurrences, write result to `Group2.txt`.
- Repeat until all files are processed. Now we have a bunch of group files.

Then I merge all these group files.

```
   Group1.txt     Group2.txt   Group3.txt     Group4.txt   
       \            /            \                /
       Group1-2.txt                Group3-4.txt
                  \                 /
                    Group1-4.txt
```

`Group1-4.txt` is the final result.

The disagreement between me and my friend is how we count the occurrences.

I suggest to use dictionary. File name template is key. Let m be partition size. (In this example it's 5000.) Then time complexity O(m), space complexity O(m).

My friend suggests to sort the name template then count the occurrence in one pass as same name templates are all together now. time complexity O(m log m), space complexity O(m).

We cannot persuade each other. Do you guys see any issues of the two methods?

Comment: The flaw in your analysis is the claim that the time complexity for the dictionary is O(m). You are going to request O(m) dictionary lookups (that's true),  but the internal implementation of the dictionary will determine the time complexity of each lookup request. I would not expect better than O(log m) time for each lookup request.

Comment: I'm willing to bet money there aren't billions of files.

Comment: @Blindy Theoretically he could.  _[Maximum number of files in a single folder: 4,294,967,295](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-files-i-can-place/07b62caa-04c7-4c8a-92bb-6ac12b737beb)_ ; and _[Files per volume  4,294,967,295 (232 minus 1 file)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781134%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)_

Comment: @user3386109: Any decent generic hash table implementation will give you amortized constant-time (O(1)) inserts, so it take O(m) time to insert (or increment if already present) m items.  If the average time for an insert was O(log m), the time for m items would be O(m log m).  O(1) amortized time is achieved by doubling the hash table size every time it needs to grow.

Comment: @LoveRight: is this a one-off problem?  If so, I'm afraid my answer was a bit overkill, and you probably don't want to spend a week implementing a super-compact string dictionary with a Radix Trie that periodically compresses itself down to a DAWG.  >.<  For a one-off, I'd just batch on a certain number of unique strings seen, and use the library  SortedDictionary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IDK if external sorting with count-merging of duplicates has been studied.  I did find a 1983 paper (see below).  Usually, sorting algorithms are designed and studied with the assumption of sorting objects by keys, so duplicate keys have different objects.  There might be some existing literature on this, but it's a very interesting problem.  Probably it's just considered an application of compact dictionaries combined with external merge-sorting.

Efficient dictionaries for storing large amounts of strings in little memory is a very well studied problem.  Most of the useful data structures can include auxiliary data for each word (in our case, a dup count).

---

TL:DR summary of useful ideas, since I rambled on in way too much detail about many things in the main body of this answer:

- Batch boundaries when your dictionary size hits a threshold, not after fixed numbers of input files.  If there were a lot of duplicates in a group of 5000 strings, you still won't be using very much memory.  You can find way more duplicates in the first pass this way.
- Sorted batches makes merging *much* faster.  You can and should merge many->one instead of binary merging.  Use a PriorityQueue to figure out which input file has the line you should take next.
- To avoid a burst of memory usage when sorting the keys in a hash table, use a dictionary that can do an in-order traversal of keys.  (i.e. sort on the fly.)  There's [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (binary tree-based).  This also interleaves the CPU usage of sorting with the I/O waiting to get the input strings.
- Radix-sort each batch into outputs by first-character (a-z, non-alphabetic that sorts before `A`, and non-alphabetic that sorts after `z`).  Or some other bucketing choice that distributes your keys well.  Use separate dictionaries for each radix bucket, and empty only the biggest into a batch when you hit your memory ceiling.  (fancier eviction heuristics than "biggest" may be worth it.)
- throttle I/O (esp. when merging), and check system CPU load and memory pressure.  Adapt behaviour accordingly to make sure you don't cause an impact when the server is most busy.
- For smaller temp files at the cost of CPU time, use a common-prefix encoding, or maybe lz4.
- A space-efficient dictionary will allow larger batch sizes (and thus a larger duplicate-finding window) for the same upper memory bound.  A [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (or better, [Radix Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree)) might be ideal, because it stores the characters within the tree nodes, with common prefixes only stored once.  [Directed Acyclic Word Graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_acyclic_finite_state_automaton) are even more compact (finding redundancy between common substrings that aren't prefixes).  Using one as a Dictionary is tricky but probably possible (see below).
- Take advantage of the fact that you don't need to delete any tree nodes or strings until you're going to empty the whole dictionary.  Use a growable array of nodes, and another growable char array that packs strings head to tail.  (Useful for a Radix Trie (multi-char nodes), but not a regular Trie where each node is a single char.)
- Depending on how the duplicates are distributed, you might or might not be able to find very many on the first pass.  This has some implications, but doesn't really change how you end up merging.

---

I'm assuming you have some directory traversal idea in mind, which can efficiently supply your code with a stream of strings to be uniquified and counted.  So I'll just say "strings" or "keys", to talk about the inputs.

Trim off as many unnecessary characters as possible (e.g. lose the `.xml` if they're all `.xml`).

---

It might be useful to do the CPU/memory intensive work on a separate machine, depending on what other hardware you have with a fast network connection to your critical production server.

You could run a simple program on the server that sends filenames over a TCP connection to a program running on another machine, where it's safe to use much more memory.  The program on the server could still do small dictionary batches, and just store them on a remote filesystem.

---

And now, since none of the other answers really put all the pieces together, here's my actual answer:

An upper bound on memory usage is easy.  Write your program to use a constant memory ceiling, regardless of input size.  Bigger inputs will lead to more merging phases, not more memory usage at any point.

The best estimate of temporary file storage space you can do without looking at the input is a *very* conservative upper bound that assumes every input string is unique.  You need some way to estimate how many input strings there will be.  (Most filesystems know how many separate files they contain, without having to walk the directory tree and count them.)

You can make some assumptions about the distribution of duplicates to make a better guess.

If *number*, rather than size, of scratch files is an issue, you can store multiple batches in the same output file, one after another.  Either put length-headers at the start of each to allow skipping forward by batch, or write byte offsets to a separate data stream.  If size is also important, see my paragraph about using frcode-style common-prefix compression.

---

As Ian Mercer points out in his answer, sorting your batches will make merging them much more efficient.  If you don't, you either risk hitting a wall where your algorithm can't make forward progress, or you need to do something like load one batch, scan another batch for entries that are in the first, and rewrite the 2nd batch with just the potentially-few matching entries removed.

Not sorting your batches makes the time complexity of the first pass O(N), but either you have to sort at some point later, or your later stages have a worst-case bound that's dramatically worse.  You want your output globally sorted, so other than RadixSort approaches, there's no avoiding an O(N log N) somewhere.

With limited batch size, O(log N) merge steps are expected, so your original analysis missed the O(N log N) complexity of your approach by ignoring what needs to happen after the phase1 batches are written.

---

The appropriate design choices change a lot depending on whether our memory ceiling is big enough to find many duplicates within one batch.  If even a complex compact data structure like a Trie doesn't help much, putting the data into a Trie and getting it out again to write a batch is a waste of CPU time.

If you can't do much duplicate-elimination within each batch anyway, then you need to optimize for putting possibly-matching keys together for the next stage.  Your first stage could group input strings by first byte, into up-to 252 or so output files (not all 256 values are legal filename characters), or into 27 or so output files (alphabet + misc), or 26+26+1 for upper/lower case + non-alphabetic.   Temp files can omit the common prefix from each string.

Then most of these first stage batches should have a much higher duplicate density.  Actually, this Radix distribution of inputs into output buckets is useful in any case, see below.

You should still sort your first-stage outputs in chunks, to give the next pass a much wider dup-find window for the same RAM.

---

I'm going to spend more time on the domain where you can find a useful amount of duplicates in the initial stream, before using up ~100MiB of RAM, or whatever you choose as an upper limit.

Obviously we add strings to some sort of dictionary to find and count duplicates on the fly, while only requiring enough storage for the set of unique strings.  Just storing strings and *then* sorting them would be significantly less efficient, because we'd hit our RAM limit much sooner without on-the-fly duplicate detection.

To minimize the phase2 work, phase1 should find and count as many duplicates as possible, reducing the total size of the p2 data.  Reducing the amount of merging work for phase2 is good, too.  **Bigger batches helps with both factors**, so it's very useful to come as close to your memory ceiling as you safely can in phase1.  Instead of writing a batch after a constant number of input strings, do it when your memory consumption nears your chosen ceiling.  Duplicates are counted and thrown away, and don't take any extra storage.

An alternative to accurate memory accounting is tracking the unique strings in your dictionary, which is easy (and done for you by the library implementation).  Accumulating the length of strings added can give you a good estimate of memory used for storing the strings, too.  Or just make an assumption about string length distribution.  Make your hash table the right size initially so it doesn't have to grow while you add elements, so you stop when it's 60% full (load factor) or something.

---

A space-efficient data structure for the dictionary increases our dup-finding window for a given memory limit.  Hash tables get badly inefficient when their load factor is too high, but the hash table itself only has to store pointers to the strings.  It's the most familiar dictionary and has a library implementations.

We know we're going to want our batch sorted once we've seen enough unique keys, so it might make sense to use a dictionary that can be traversed in sorted order.  **Sorting on the fly makes sense because keys will come in slowly**, limited by disk IO since we're reading from filesystem metadata.  One downside is if most of the keys we see are duplicates, then we're doing a lot of O(log batchsize) lookups, rather than a lot of O(1) lookups.  And it's more likely that a key will be a duplicate when the dictionary is big, so most of those O(log batchsize) queries will be with a batch size near max, not uniformly distributed between 0 and max.  A tree pays the O(log n) overhead of sorting for every lookup, whether the key turned out to be unique or not.  A hash table only pays the sorting cost at the end after removing duplicates.  So for a tree it's O(total_keys * log unique_keys), hash table is O(unique_keys * log unique_keys) to sort a batch.

A hash table with max load factor set to 0.75 or something might be pretty dense, but having to sort the `KeyValuePair`s before writing out a batch probably puts a damper on using standard Dictionary.  You don't need copies of the strings, but you'll probably end up copying all the pointers (refs) to scratch space for a non-in-place sort, and maybe also when getting them out of the hash table before sorting.   (Or instead of just pointers, KeyValuePair, to avoid having to go back and look up each string in the hash table).    If short spikes of big memory consumption are tolerable, and don't cause you to swap / page to disk, you could be fine.  This is avoidable if you can do an in-place sort in the buffer used by the hash table, but I doubt that can happen with standard-library containers.

A constant trickle of CPU usage to maintain the sorted dictionary at the speed keys are available is probably better than infrequent bursts of CPU usage to sort all of a batch's keys, besides the burst of memory consumption.

The .NET standard library has [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which the docs say is implemented with a binary tree.  I didn't check if it has a rebalance function, or uses a red-black tree, to guarantee O(log n) worst case performance.  I'm not sure how much memory overhead it would have.  If this is a one-off task, then I'd absolutely recommend using this to implement it quickly and easily.  And also for a first version of a more optimized design for repeated use.  You'll probably find it's good enough, unless you can find a nice library implementation of Tries.

---

### Data structures for memory-efficient sorted dictionaries

The more memory efficient out dictionary is, the more dups we can find before having to write out a batch and delete the dictionary.  Also, if it's a sorted dictionary, the larger our batches can be even when they can't find duplicates.

A secondary impact of data structure choice is how much memory traffic we generate while running on the critical server.  A sorted array (with O(log n) lookup time (binary search), and O(n) insert time (shuffle elements to make room)) would be compact.  However, it wouldn't just be slow, it would saturate memory bandwidth with memmove a lot of the time.  100% CPU usage doing this would have a bigger impact on the server's performance than 100% CPU usage searching a binary tree.  It doesn't know where to load the next node from until it's loaded the current node, so it can't pipeline memory requests.  The branch mispredicts of comparisons in the tree search also help moderate consumption of the memory bandwidth that's shared by all cores.  (That's right, some 100%-CPU-usage programs are worse than others!)

It's nice if emptying our dictionary doesn't leave memory fragmented when we empty it.  Tree nodes will be constant size, though, so a bunch of scattered holes will be usable for future tree node allocations.  However, if we have separate dictionaries for multiple radix buckets (see below), key strings associated with other dictionaries might be mixed in with tree nodes.  This could lead to malloc having a hard time reusing all the freed memory, potentially increasing actual OS-visible memory usage by some small factor.  (Unless C# runtime garbage collection does compaction, in which case fragmentation is taken care of.)

Since you never need to delete nodes until you want to empty the dictionary and delete them all, you could store your Tree nodes in a growable array.  So memory management only has to keep track of one big allocation, reducing bookkeeping overhead compared to malloc of each node separately.  Instead of real pointers, the left / right child pointers could be array indices.  This lets you use only 16 or 24 bits for them.  (A [Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) is another kind of binary tree stored in an array, but it can't be used efficiently as a dictionary.  It's a tree, but not a *search* tree).

Storing the string keys for a dictionary would normally be done with each String as a separately-allocated object, with pointers to them in an array.  Since again, you never need to delete, grow, or even modify one until you're ready to delete them all, you can pack them head to tail in a char array, with a terminating zero-byte at the end of each one.  This again saves a lot of book-keeping, and also makes it easy to keep track of how much memory is in use for the key strings, letting you safely come closer to your chosen memory upper bound.

### Trie / DAWG for even more compact storage

For even denser storage of a set of strings, we can eliminate the redundancy of storing all the characters of every string, since there are probably a lot of common prefixes.

A [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) stores the strings in the tree structure, giving you common-prefix compression.  It can be traversed in sorted order, so it sorts on the fly.  Each node has as many children as there are different next-characters in the set, so it's not a binary tree.  A C# Trie partial implementation (delete not written) can be found in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12396706/224132), to a question similar to this but not requiring batching / external sorting.

Trie nodes need to store potentially many child pointers, so each node can be large.  Or each node could be variable-size, holding the list of nextchar:ref pairs inside the node, if C# makes that possible.  Or as the Wikipedia article says, a node can actually be a linked-list or binary search tree, to avoid wasting space in nodes with few children.  (The lower levels of a tree will have a lot of that.)  End-of-word markers / nodes are needed to distinguish between substrings that aren't separate dictionary entries, and ones that are.  Our count field can serve that purpose.  Count=0 means the substring ending here isn't in the dictionary.  count>=0 means it is.

A more compact Trie is the [Radix Tree, or PATRICIA Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree), which stores multiple characters per node.

Another extension of this idea is the [Deterministic acyclic finite state automaton (DAFSA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_acyclic_finite_state_automaton), sometimes called a Directed Acyclic Word Graph (DAWG), but note that the [DAWG wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph) is about a different thing with the same name.  I'm not sure a DAWG can be traversed in sorted order to get all the keys out at the end, and as wikipedia points out, storing associated data (like a duplicate count) requires a modification.  I'm also not sure they can be built incrementally, but I think you can do lookups without having compacted.  The newly added entries will be stored like a Trie, until a compaction step every 128 new keys merges them into the DAWG.  (Or run the compaction less frequently for bigger DAWGs, so you aren't doing it too much, like doubling the size of a hash table when it has to grow, instead of growing linearly, to amortize the expensive op.)

You can make a DAWG more compact by storing multiple characters in a single node when there isn't any branching / converging.  [This page](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads//HTML/directedAcyclicWordGraph.html) also mentions a Huffman-coding approach to compact DAWGs, and has some other links and article citations.

[JohnPaul Adamovsky's DAWG implementation (in C)](http://pages.pathcom.com/~vadco/dawg.html) looks good, and describes some optimizations it uses.  I haven't looked carefully to see if it can map strings to counts.  It's optimized to store all the nodes in an array.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190326/parsing-one-terabyte-of-text-and-efficiently-counting-the-number-of-occurrences#comment31962178_12399830) to the dup-count words in 1TB of text question suggests DAWGs, and has a couple links, but I'm not sure how useful it is.

---

### Writing batches: Radix on first character

You could get your RadixSort on, and keep separate dictionaries for every starting character (or for a-z, non-alphabetic that sorts before a, non-alphabetic that sorts after z).  Each dictionary writes out to a different temp file.  If you have multiple compute nodes available for a MapReduce approach, this would be the way to distribute merging work to the compute nodes.

This allows an interesting modification: instead of writing all radix buckets at once, **only write the largest dictionary as a batch**.  This prevents tiny batches going into some buckets each time you.  This will reduce the width of the merging within each bucket, speeding up phase2.

With a binary tree, this reduces the depth of each tree by about log2(num_buckets), speeding up lookups.  With a Trie, this is redundant (*each* node uses the next character as a radix to order the child trees).  With a DAWG, this actually hurts your space-efficiency because you lose out on finding the redundancy between strings with different starts but later shared parts.

This has the potential to behave poorly if there are a few infrequently-touched buckets that keep growing, but don't usually end up being the largest.  They could use up a big fraction of your total memory, making for small batches from the commonly-used buckets.  You could implement a smarter eviction algorithm that records when a bucket (dictionary) was last emptied.  The NeedsEmptying score for a bucket would be something like a product of size and age.  Or maybe some function of age, like sqrt(age).  Some way to record how many duplicates each bucket has found since last emptied would be useful, too.  If you're in a spot in your input stream where there are a lot of repeats for one of the buckets, the last thing you want to do is empty it frequently.  Maybe every time you find a duplicate in a bucket, increment a counter.  Look at the ratio of age vs. dups-found.  Low-use buckets sitting there taking RAM away from other buckets will be easy to find that way, when their size starts to creep up.  Really-valuable buckets might be kept even when they're the current biggest, if they're finding a lot of duplicates.

If your data structures for tracking age and dups found is a struct-of-arrays, the `(last_emptied[bucket] - current_pos) / (float)dups_found[bucket]` division can be done efficiently with vector floating point.  One integer division is slower than one FP division.  One FP division is the same speed as 4 FP divisions, and compilers can hopefully auto-vectorize if you make it easy for them like this.

There's a lot of work to do between buckets filling up, so division would be a tiny hiccup unless you use a *lot* of buckets.

## choosing how to bucket

With a good eviction algorithm, an ideal choice of bucketing will put keys that rarely have duplicates together in some buckets, and buckets that have many duplicates together in other buckets.  If you're aware of any patterns in your data, this would be a way to exploit it.  Having some buckets that are mostly low-dup means that all those unique keys don't wash away the valuable keys into an output batch.  An eviction algorithm that looks at how valuable a bucket has been in terms of dups found per unique key will automatically figure out which buckets are valuable and worth keeping, even though their size is creeping up.

There are *many* ways to radix your strings into buckets.  Some will ensure that every element in a bucket compares less than every element in every later bucket, so producing fully-sorted output is easy.  Some won't, but have other advantages.  There are going to be tradeoffs between bucketing choices, all of which are data-dependent:

- good at finding a lot of duplicates in the first pass (e.g. by separating high-dup patterns from low-dup patterns)
- distributes the number of batches uniformly between buckets (so no bucket has a huge number of batches requiring a multi-stage merge in phase2), and maybe other factors.
- produces bad behaviour when combined with your eviction algorithm on your data set.
- amount of between-bucket merging needed to produce globally-sorted output.  The importance of this scales with the total number of unique strings, not the number of input strings.

I'm sure clever people have thought about good ways to bucket strings before me, so this is probably worth searching on if the obvious approach of by-first-character isn't ideal.  This special use-case (of sorting while eliminating/counting duplicates) is not typical.  I think most work on sorting only considers sorts that preserve duplicates.  So you might not find much that helps choose a good bucketing algorithm for a dup-counting external sort.  In any case, it will be data-dependent.

Some concrete-options for bucketing are: Radix = first two bytes together (still combining upper/lowercase, and combining non-alphabetic characters).  Or Radix = the first byte of the hash code.  (Requires a global-merge to produce sorted output.)  Or Radix = `(str[0]>>2) << 6 + str[1]>>2`.  i.e. ignore the low 2 bits of the first 2 chars, to put `[abcd][abcd].*` together, `[abcd][efgh].*` together, etc.  This would also require some merging of the sorted results between some sets of buckets.  e.g. `daxxx` would be in the first bucket, but `aexxx` would be in the 2nd.  But only buckets with the same first-char high-bits need to be merged with each other to produce the sorted final output.

An idea for handling a bucketing choice that gives great dup-finding but needs merge-sorting between buckets:  When writing the phase2 output, bucket it with the first character as the radix to produce the sort order you want.  Each phase1 bucket scatters output into phase2 buckets as part of the global sort.  Once all the phase1 batches that can include strings starting with `a` have been processed, do the merge of the `a` phase2-bucket into the final output and delete those temp files.

Radix = first 2 bytes (combining non-alphabetic) would make for for 28<sup>2</sup> = 784 buckets.  With 200MiB of RAM, that's average output file size of only ~256k.  Emptying just one bucket at a time would make that the minimum, and you'd usually get larger batches, so this could work.  (Your eviction algorithm could hit a pathological case that made it keep a lot of big buckets, and write a series of tiny batches for new buckets.  There are dangers to clever heuristics if you don't test carefully).

Multiple batches packed into the same output file is probably most useful with many small buckets.  You'll have e.g. 784 output files, each containing a series of batches.  Hopefully your filesystem has enough contiguous free space, and is smart enough, to do a good job of not fragmenting too badly when scattering small-ish writes to many files.

---

### Merging:

In the merging stages, with sorted batches we don't need a dictionary.  Just take the next line from the batch that has the lowest, combining duplicates as you find them.

MergeSort typically merges pairs, but [when doing external sorting (i.e. disk -> disk)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting), a much wider input is common to avoid reading and re-writing the output a lot of times.  Having 25 input files open to merge into one output file should be fine.  Use the library implementation of PriorityQueue (typically implemented as a Heap) to choose the next input element from many sorted lists.  Maybe add input lines with the string as the priority, and the count and input file number as payload.

If you used radix distribute-by-first-character in the first pass, then merge all the `a` batches into the final output file (even if this process takes multiple merging stages), then all the `b` batches, etc.  **You don't need to check any of the batches from the starts-with-`a` bucket against batches from any other bucket**, so this saves a *lot* of merging work, esp. if your keys are well distributed by first character.

---

### Minimizing impact on the production server:

Throttle disk I/O during merging, to avoid bringing your server to its knees if disk prefetch generates a huge I/O queue depth of reads.  Throttling your I/O, rather than a narrower merge, is probably a better choice.  If the server is busy with its normal job, it prob. won't be doing many big sequential reads even if you're only reading a couple files.

Check the system load occasionally while running.  If it's high, sleep for 1 sec before doing some more work and checking again.  If it's really high, don't do any more work until the load average drops (sleeping 30sec between checks).

Check the system memory usage, too, and reduce your batch threshold if memory is tight on the production server.  (Or if really tight, flush your partial batch and sleep until memory pressure reduces.)

If temp-file size is an issue, you could do [common-prefix compression like frcode from updatedb/locate](https://github.com/c9/node-gnu-tools/blob/master/findutils-src/locate/frcode.c) to significantly reduce the file size for sorted lists of strings.  Probably use case-sensitive sorting within a batch, but case-insensitive radixing.  So each batch in the `a` bucket  will have all the `A`s, then all the `a`s.  Or even LZ4 compress / decompress them on the fly.  Use hex for the counts, not decimal.  It's shorter, and faster to encode/decode.

Use a separator that's not a legal filename character, like `/`, between key and count.  String parsing might well take up a lot of the CPU time in the merge stage, so it's worth considering.  If you can leave strings in per-file input buffers, and just point your PQueue at them, that might be good.  (And tell you which input file a string came from, without storing that separately.)

---

performance tuning:

If the initial unsorted strings were available extremely fast, then a hash table with small batches that fit the dictionary in the CPU L3 cache might be a win, unless a larger window can include a much larger fraction of keys, and find more dups.  It depends on how many repeats are typical in say 100k files.  Build small sorted batches in RAM as you read, then merge them to a disk batch.  This may be more efficient than doing a big in-memory quicksort, since you don't have random access to the input until you've initially read it.

Since I/O will probably be the limit, large batches that don't fit in the CPU's data cache are probably a win, to find more duplicates and (greatly?) reduce the amount of merging work to be done.

It might be convenient to check the hash table size / memory consumption after every chunk of filenames you get from the OS, or after every subdirectory or whatever.  As long as you choose a conservative size bound, and you make sure you can't go for too long without checking, you don't need to go nuts checking every iteration.

---

[This paper from 1983](http://dc-pubs.dbs.uni-leipzig.de/files/Bitton1983Duplicaterecordeliminationin.pdf) examines external merge-sorting eliminating duplicates as they're encountered, and also suggests duplicate elimination with a hash function and a bitmap.  With long input strings, storing MD5 or SHA1 hashes for duplicate-elimination saves a lot of space.

I'm not sure what they had in mind with their bitmap idea.  Being collision-resistant enough to be usable without going back to check the original string would require a hash code of too many bits to index a reasonable-size bitmap.  (e.g. MD5 is a 128bit hash).

Comment: The long answer I have ever seen in SE :). Hats off to your efforts.

Comment: @sunrise76: yeah, I kinda went overboard.  If I was in academia, I'd have thought about actually writing this up as a paper to publish.  It combines the theoretical with a novel implementation constraint (don't bog down the production server), and I thinking of new ideas.  This question was what got me interested in the topic, so this seemed like a good place to brain-dump everything I thought of (and later, stuff I found about Tries and DAWGs, after going looking for compact dictionary data structures.  Pretty much everything else I came up with on my own, except N-way external merging :)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! It's a good idea to do analysis on another computer. For now I will use one thread to enumerate files and the other thread to sort and count the files with SortedDictionary.

Comment: @LoveRight: sounds like a good plan.  For sending batches over the network (e.g. writing to a fileserver), it may make sense to compress them with some lightweight compressor.  Common-prefix `frcode` + lz4 should probably do very well on sorted batches, and be very light on the CPU.  Pick whatever's appropriate for how important network bandwidth is.  `frcode` will help a lot if there are long common prefixes (it's great for a `locate` database that stores the full path of every file on the system).

Comment: In regards to DAWG, it's not too tricky to use it as a dictionary, as all you need to do is tunnel until a required vertice doesn't exist, or you reach the length of the key you're looking for. One can store a count or value on the node as well as an End-Of-Word flag. Sorting could be achieved by inserting new vertices in sorted order, maybe using SortedList<T> or similar.

Comment: @MattSearles: A character or string in a DAWG can be the end of multiple different words.  (And yes, you indicate that with an end-of-word flag.)  Storing associated data (like a count) is harder, though, because you need to tell *which* word you reached the end of.  IIRC, one of the links I found suggested using the path through the DAWG as an array index into an array of associated data, or something like that.

Comment: @Christoph: Thanks, I didn't come across https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burstsort while researching this answer.  If you change it to count dups, it should do well.  Using a trie + keeping suffixes should be ideal for pathnames if there's any common prefix.

Comment: Suprised b+tree isn't an ideal candidate for this? Seems that it would hit a nice sweet spot between sort as you go and efficient insertion. Also if the data has a reasonable distribution could imagine implementing it in a fixed array with a priority queue esq layout so their would be no need to store anything other than the string pointers.

Comment: @Noah: sure, that sounds like a good suggestion.  Is it good for in-memory storage, though?  Or do you mean using a memory-mapped file to build it on disk?  I don't have a lot of experience with B-trees or [B+ trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree).  Is it good for building on the fly?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree#Bulk-loading suggests sorting separately, before creating a B+ tree from a chunk of data.  So perhaps good for the external part, still using a radix trie for the in-memory part?  i.e. merge into a B+ tree every batch instead of doing all merging at the end.

Comment: @Noah: If you want to write up a B+ tree answer, you're more than welcome.  IIRC, my current answer is bumping into the 30k char limit so I'm probably not going to edit.

Comment: Hmm, never saw that method for bulk loading before. If that is infact that case I can't imagine sort -> B+Tree is more efficient than sort -> Check hashset -> if not in append to array. But to skip the pointer chasing I could imagine something like semi sorting with the radix trie in RAM then clearing the radix trie to a B+Tree s.t each leaf of the radix trie would share at least some common pointers. Maybe if I end up implementing it and has good performance (have a similiar problem to this post myself).

Answer (score 4):

How do you "merge the group files" in your approach? In worst case every line had a different name template so each group file had 5,000 lines in it and each merge doubles the number of lines until you overflow memory.

Your friend is closer to the answer, those intermediate files need to be sorted so you can read them line by line and merge them to create new files without having to hold them all in memory. This is a well-known problem, it's an [external sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting). Once sorted you can count the results.

Comment: Great point.  Sorting each batch also means you don't need to build a new dictionary when merging two batches.

Comment: Oh, yes.. I later realized the problem of my method. Thanks for the wiki link.

Answer (score 2):

A jolly good problem.

Considering that you intend to process the results in batches of **5000**, I don't believe *memory optimisations* will be of particular importance so we could probably ignore that aspect like a bad *Adam Sandler* film and move onto the more exciting stuff.  Besides, just because some computation uses more RAM does not necessarily imply it's a bad algorithm.  No one ever complained about *look-up* tables.

However, I do agree *computationally* the **dictionary approach is better** because it's **faster**.  With respect to the alternative, why perform an unnecessary sort even if its quick?  The latter, with its  "O(m log m)" is ultimately slower than "O(m)".

### The Real Problem?

With RAM out of the equation, the problem is essentially that of *computation*.  Any "performance problem" in the algorithm will arguably be **insignificant** to the **time it takes to traverse the file system in the first place**.

That's arguably where the real challenge will be.  A problem for another time perhaps?

**EDIT**: displayName makes a good point about using Hadoop - quite ideal for concurrent jobs and compute

Good luck!

Comment: This misses the point that you should sort at some point to make merging efficient.  Reducing I/O load and temp file size by finding more duplicates before writing out a batch is potentially useful.  See my answer.  The problem is to avoid bogging down a production server.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a very good candidate for **Map-Reduce**. Great news: You don't need to *move from C# to Java (Hadoop)* as [Map-Reduce is possible in .NET framework!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428798/map-and-reduce-in-net)

Through LINQs you have the basic elements of execution in place already for performing Map Reduce in C#. This might be one advantage over going for External Sort though there is no question about the observation behind External Sort. [This link](http://codecube.net/2009/02/mapreduce-in-c-using-linq/) has the *'Hello World!'* of Map-Reduce already implemented in C# using LINQs and should get you started.

---

If you do move to Java, one of the most comprehensive tutorial about it is [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html). Google about Hadoop and Map-Reduce and you will get plenty of information  and numerous good online video tutorials.

Further, if you wish to move to Java, your requirements of:

- Sorted results
- critical RAM usage

will surely be met as they are inbuilt fulfillments you get from a Map-Reduce job in Hadoop.

Comment: There is no need to move to Java, you can do Map-Reduce with [Enumerable.Select and Enumerable.Aggregate](http://www.25hoursaday.com/weblog/2008/06/16/FunctionalProgrammingInC30HowMapReduceFilterCanRockYourWorld.aspx).

Comment: Unless you have multiple servers to distribute the work to, limiting yourself to a single thread on the OP's "critical server" is going to have less impact on whatever else that server needs to be doing.  A framework that has building blocks for this, and lets you set a memory ceiling, has clear advantages for a quick non-optimal implementation, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes: It doesn't have to be multiple servers. It can be multiple threads on the same server.

Comment: @displayName: If you read the OP's question, it's pretty clear he wants to avoid disrupting the operation of a critical server.  Using multiple threads, each with their own memory consumption, is a terrible idea for **this** specific case.  It'd be better to use your whole memory budget on a single thread, to find more dups in phase1.  Minimizing total disk I/O and CPU time, and avoiding load spikes, is much more important than minimizing wall-clock time here.  Depending on how many unique keys there are, a single thread with a big dictionary might be best even without the load constraint.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Avoiding disruption of critical server's operations goes without saying. What OP wants though is - "be able to tell memory usage (MB) and the number of temporary files generated". Both conditions can be met with this approach. Further, Map-Reduce is especially for these kinds of heavy jobs. It does *Speculative Execution* (google it). And that is because it is not a wise idea to leave such heavy task to a single thread because if it crashes, all work is lost. MR is therefore definitely not a "terrible" idea. :D

Comment: trying to rephrase / summarize: a single-threaded program can probably come close enough to maxing out disk I/O and CPU usage at the same time, when the system isn't busy so the OS can do disk readahead and buffer writes.  If the system is busy, that's exactly when you want to use fewer resources, instead of having multiple threads to take as big a share as you can of all the system resources.  I expect phase1 and phase2 to be I/O bound, and two threads each reading from 50 files isn't going to be very friendly to other jobs.  Merging is prob. very light on CPU, limiting value for an IO thread

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89742/discussion-between-peter-cordes-and-displayname).

Comment: Ok, well anyway, my argument is that the only big gain from multithreading would be an IO thread in phase1.  In phase2, maybe it makes sense to have an IO thread to refill buffers with big (but slow) reads of maybe 4MB, to minimize disk thrashing compared to reading 128k every time the buffer had that much room.  (5M * 50 input files = 250MiB of read buffers, assuming a 1MiB low-water-mark in 5M circular buffers, to usually trigger 4MiB reads.)  Doing this in a single thread isn't terrible though: having small gaps without an outstanding I/O request is more load-friendly.

Comment: @PeterCordes: That's very contradictory. First off, **No**, a single-threaded program **cannot** come close enough to maxing out disk I/O and CPU usage at the same time *because there is a lot of mismatch between the speed of processor vs speed of I/O from disk* (unless you are on an ancient machine). Secondly, **yes, even though if the system is busy, you want to use fewer resources** still AFAIK *threads are very light-weight.*

Comment: @displayName: It depends how much work you do for each byte of I/O, obviously.  And re: system load: it's not the thread itself that's the problem, it's what a thread allows you to do.  You can keep a read pending at all times, instead of just between bursts of CPU activity.  Depending on which thread writes, you're even keeping a read pending while blocked on a write, increasing I/O queue depth.

Comment: Map-Reduce is a too general technique. How do I map and reduce? I probably still need to adopt Peter Cordes's suggestions.

Comment: @LoveRight: If you want specific implementation, I can try my hand at it. Map-Reduce is the algo, just like the other (most up-voted) answer here 'External Sorting'. Both MR and ES are tried and tested techniques and are used in the industry (coincidentally, both by Google). But if Peter's suggestions work perfectly for you, you should use them.

Comment: @LoveRight: My solution is external sorting; I'm just optimizing it.  If you can afford the memory to find a lot of duplicates in the first pass by using a compact dictionary (like a Radix Tree), that can save a lot of I/O writing and re-reading temp files.  Even the library-implementation SortedDictionary should be a win because you don't need extra memory to sort it when you need to write it out.  Apparently distributing phase1 output to buckets by radix on the first character is a standard external sorting technique.  A progress checkpoint (directory position?) after each batch is good.