# simulate jg instruction(datalab's isGreater)

Tags: c, assembly, instructions, eflags

I am doing CSAPP's datalab, the isGreater function.

Here's the description

```
isGreater - if x > y  then return 1, else return 0
   Example: isGreater(4,5) = 0, isGreater(5,4) = 1
   Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>
   Max ops: 24
   Rating: 3
```

x and y are both int type.

So i consider to simulate the jg instruction to implement it.Here's my code

```
int isGreater(int x, int y)
{
    int yComplement = ~y + 1;
    int minusResult = x + yComplement;  // 0xffffffff
    int SF = (minusResult >> 31) & 0x1; // 1
    int ZF = !minusResult; // 0
    int xSign = (x >> 31) & 0x1; // 0 
    int ySign = (yComplement >> 31) & 0x1; // 1
    int OF = !(xSign ^ ySign) & (xSign ^ SF); // 0
    return !(OF ^ SF) & !ZF;
}
```

The jg instruction need SF == OF and ZF == 0.

But it can't pass a special case, that is, x = 0x7fffffff(INT_MAX), y = 0x80000000(INT_MIN).

I deduce it like this:

x + yComplement = 0xffffffff,  so SF = 1, ZF = 0, since xSign != ySign, the OF is set to 0.

So, what's wrong with my code, is my OF setting operation wrong?

Comment: If you use `unsigned int`, you don't need `& 1` after a shift.  (And as a bonus, it would avoid C signed-overflow undefined behaviour in `+`: http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).  Or you can use `& 0x80000000` to leave the high bits in place (and I guess left shift your `!` result).  Anyway, those are just ways to more efficiently do what you're already doing.

Comment: assuming two's complement, `INT_MIN`'s absolute value isn't representable as an `int`. So, `yComplement == y` (ie. still negative), and `ySign` is `1` instead of `0`.

Comment: **You're detecting overflow in the addition `x + yComplement`, rather than in the overall subtraction**


`-INT_MIN` itself overflows, on a 2's complement system.
  writing a full answer, will post soon.

Comment: @PeterCordes It's just the lab's restriction, you can't use unsigned or any constant larger than 0xff(255)

Comment: lol, that's amusing that they force you to write it non-portably.  I guess you're supposed to assume that right shift of `int` is an arithmetic right shift?  So they deny you access to logical right shift?

Comment: @PeterCordes exactly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You're detecting overflow in the addition `x + yComplement`, rather than in the overall subtraction**

`-INT_MIN` itself overflows in 2's complement; `INT_MIN == -INT_MIN`.  This is [the 2's complement anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Most_negative_number)<sup>1</sup>.

You should be getting fast-positive overflow detection for any negative number (other than `INT_MIN`) minus `INT_MIN`.  The resulting addition will have signed overflow.  e.g. `-10 + INT_MIN` overflows.

http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt has a table of input/output signs for add and subtraction.  The cases that overflow are where the inputs signs are opposite but the result sign matches `y`.

```
      SUBTRACTION SIGN BITS  (for num1 - num2 = sum)
    num1sign num2sign sumsign
   ---------------------------
        0 0 0
        0 0 1
        0 1 0
 *OVER* 0 1 1 (subtracting a negative is the same as adding a positive)
 *OVER* 1 0 0 (subtracting a positive is the same as adding a negative)
        1 0 1
        1 1 0
        1 1 1
```

You could use this directly with the original `x` and `y`, and only use `yComplement` as part of getting the `minusResult`.  Adjust your logic to match this truth table.

**Or you could use `int ySign = (~y) >> 31;` and leave the rest of your code unmodified**.  (Use a tmp to hold `~y` so you only do the operation once, for this and `yComplement`).  The one's complement inverse (`~`) does not suffer from the 2's complement anomaly.

---

**Footnote 1**: sign/magnitude and one's complement have two redundant ways to represent 0, instead of an value with no inverse.

Fun fact: if you make an integer absolute-value function, you should consider the result `unsigned` to avoid this problem.  `int` can't represent the absolute value of `INT_MIN`.

---

## Efficiency improvements:

If you use `unsigned int`, you don't need `& 1` after a shift because logical shifts don't sign-extend.  (And as a bonus, it would avoid C signed-overflow undefined behaviour in `+`: http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).

Then (if you used `uint32_t`, or `sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT` instead of 31) you'd have a safe and portable implementation of 2's complement comparison.  (signed shift semantics for negative numbers are implementation-defined in C.)  I think you're using C as a sort of pseudo-code for bit operations, and aren't interested in actually writing a portable implementation, and that's fine.  The way you're doing things will work on normal compilers on normal CPUs.

Or you can use `& 0x80000000` to leave the high bits in place (but then you'd have to left shift your `!` result).

> It's just the lab's restriction, you can't use unsigned or any constant larger than 0xff(255)

Ok, so you don't have access to logical right shift.  Still, you need at most one `&1`.  It's ok to work with numbers where all you care about is the low bit, but where the rest hold garbage.

You eventually do `& !ZF`, which is either `&0` or &1`.  Thus, any high garbage in` OF` is wiped away.

You can also delay the `>> 31` until after XORing together two numbers.

---

#### This is a fun problem that I want to optimize myself:

```
// untested, 13 operations
int isGreater_optimized(int x, int y)
{
    int not_y = ~y;
    
    int minus_y = not_y + 1;
    int sum = x + minus_y;

    int x_vs_y = x ^ y;       // high bit = 1 if they were opposite signs: OF is possible
    int x_vs_sum = x ^ sum;   // high bit = 1 if they were opposite signs: OF is possible

    int OF = (x_vs_y & x_vs_sum) >> 31;   // high bits hold garbage
    int SF = sum >> 31;

    int non_zero = !!sum;              // 0 or 1
    return (~(OF ^ SF)) & non_zero;      // high garbage is nuked by `& 1`
}
```

Note the use of `~` instead of `!` to invert a value that has high garbage.

It looks like there's still some redundancy in calculating OF separately from SF, but actually the XORing of sum twice doesn't cancel out.  `x ^ sum` is an input for `&`, and we XOR with sum after that.

We can delay the shifts even later, though, and I found some more optimizations by avoiding an extra inversion.  **This is 11 operations**

```
// replace 31 with  sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT  if you want.  #include <limit.h>
// or use int32_t

int isGreater_optimized2(int x, int y)
{
    int not_y = ~y;

    int minus_y = not_y + 1;
    int sum = x + minus_y;
    int SF = sum;             // value in the high bit, rest are garbage

    int x_vs_y = x ^ y;       // high bit = 1 if they were opposite signs: OF is possible
    int x_vs_sum = x ^ sum;   // high bit = 1 if they were opposite signs: OF is possible
    int OF = x_vs_y & x_vs_sum;   // low bits hold garbage

    int less = (OF ^ SF);
    int ZF   = !sum;               // 0 or 1
    int le   = (less >> 31) & ZF;  // clears high garbage
    return  !le;                   // jg == jnle
}
```

I wondered if any compilers might see through this manual compare and optimize it into `cmp edi, esi`/ `setg al`, but no such luck :/  I guess that's not a pattern that they look for, because code that could have been written as `x > y` tends to *be* written that way :P

But anyway, here's [the x86 asm output from gcc and clang on the Godbolt compiler explorer.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5HhYEA1HkEBxYpiYFMxAPqoADgTwBbPAC9M6CLIUAPUornyAngEoOABgCCHAOx8v8oEOCiyoBNpO8hwAzAAi8gB%2BTjH%2B3gFB1vImLCKCEVFx8qHhkfzytCkenkHB8oIiRgXxNlG8WbK5EZVeVTWZNtoAbnmlhS0cAKzYzik1QQD08/IIeMAI8gBGhE3ligBm8gQImJEA7lqY8vp6qIKEl3fALIIg8gDyAGKKgvI3gncbBiYXoZRwDYbaeqNGLNKJTOoNWaBRbLVbrLYKGG7PAHI4neTnNRXPR/e51VbPV6fb6/W4AoFVEGBTLUrEQcEjVoANnkHMhDRcBWwMWm0Qq0R4CyWKzWm0IPwQqAY6HkwCYxA2TGAwPSzMcAGUvlioUKRfIxd00tVQSFUCxtOZiKgdmBXWAoUi5l75Cj3FdiOUmfI1AQxCx5BAEhBWfDDS5BdweaF7Y7UJ6pajZWqNVrLkoiiIANYWTalLnuROB8uMnyxRleTJKVTqTQ6fSGEzmdBcKxg%2ByZVw11J9RzFfJYpKWoOZbKdUbxMelNri4c2hHQsatSWzkaWkcKQ07D0S71elGDJgMER58N4zPowj2NSCBTqy7ZzXa%2BvWvW2IacrFxnhZITzPaU0TlTFClofZDmOM4LmJUlNHJJ4XneL58z%2BekdR/Wo%2BRNQC4WmY9JWRcDZQxHYYJxOD8UJS5rluMlHkpDCaWwvBAVw/d2MA/9xy4HkCMRUCfSWBhUFOSCFSVFUP1zb9eKBf4dmjI1Yw%2BNwJWnRwAC0vkCLFXVI09vV9f1A11WogSCNkVJ%2BEUzTFBMhPkAykRRZAgXVBUIIUr9rJDMNAldBkxLM8ylioYAmixKgWAZHpayqKQXEYaQJikUgWGkdxstQaQAGF%2BDKYQxAkVoxWygg8rS9LCxAaIfAAOloLgJncaJoncABOAAWLr%2Btofr%2BoyqR%2Buyow6Hcdwcrq0hCqkbKXjm2qpHy9K4FgJA0CMPQ8CBMgKAgPaDqOlBmDYcs5r2Q7WxeCANgWrYWHVJxpFobK9qMTA5DeRKPo27KsCMVhgCBBb8DUZBDEGTAXmB0hMBsTBkBETRPuy6xMAYBaCGIYwsfSq72FK3hGC4l5IHS9s8DtRGAFoAHVLwYeRGbeaIVtEcRJFoEnMuy3KkaWmwAA4uUZrl%2BvkbzwfkLkWvcZWI1wQgSCq%2Bh5CK1B9sOrQtcFEreH4Gq6vjUhGq4XqWq4Hx2t6mWevLfquH6iZxsm0hptoWb5tF6QVpANaLdIbbEBQPXzq0chKDOg3iBAYBxfoO6GAeyhnqR173qx0gfr%2BggAYYIH8tIUHwchpHobRuGEYWlG0YxyQpC%2B8g5Fx/HCemtu0sYcGUHJgQGCp%2BBaYMenKSkTnuaEXmJDoQWpCygPy7FyXpdl4BkGQeRxbatX8CIANuDFexdf1o6qq4Y3h/N4HLeOJgsCTiAGqa6IWvLaIuR8dx%2Bo%2BAmL/WgXJ6B4wmsLBaS1g6h0fsvLgUDA7LVIOtTa6V4bEDuHaEA/UgA%3D)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming two's complement, `INT_MIN`'s absolute value isn't representable as an `int`. So, `yComplement == y` (ie. still negative), and `ySign` is `1` instead of the desired `0`.

You could instead calculate the sign of `y` like this (changing as little as possible in your code) :

```
int ySign = !((y >> 31) & 0x1);
```

For a more detailed analysis, and a more optimal alternative, check [Peter Cordes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51169016/822669).

Comment: heh, just as a finished typing up my answer.  I got wrapped up in optimizing my own version of the function :P

Comment: @PeterCordes : sorry - I assumed you got side tracked, but I wasn't counting on you coming up with the mother of all answers ;)

Comment: Yeah, no worries.  And BTW, my answer is nowhere *near* the "mother of all answers".  That would be [Why is this C++ code faster than my hand-written assembly for testing the Collatz conjecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40355466) (which links to a bunch of other answer I've written, so you could literally say it's the mother :P).  I also hit the 30k char limit on [Memory-constrained external sorting of strings, with duplicates combined&counted, on a critical server (billions of filenames)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32537772), without any big code blocks or giant Godbolt links.